# Stack Exchange for in-house use

Tags: discussion, support, so-engine, private-site

Is Stack Overflow's implementation available for in-house use (à la MediaWiki)? I'm thinking my company could really benefit from the kind of service Stack Overflow provides, but the entire implementation would have to be kept in-house to protect company IP, etc.

Comment: @fbrereton: If someone's answer was perfect for you, you should mark it as "correct" using the check mark on the left side of the post.

Comment: My answer to this question corrected earlier answers to this question, but it has now become outdated itself. See my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions/96031#96031) instead.