# Showing posts only to logged on users?

Tags: discussion, area-51

This is a bit of an odd question. I do have an idea for a possible site, but before I even propose it I wanted to check if there is something that Stack Exchange software can do (or be updated to do), namely keep posts locked so only logged in users can see them.

The idea is to use the Stack Exchange model for a Writer's Workshop type site. Author can both post questions and stories to be critiqued. The second type of post is the problem, any stories that are posted can not be publicly viewable otherwise an author risks losing their first serial rights (I've been a magazine editor/publisher in the past, so I know how serious this is. My rule of thumb was that if Google can find it, it's published).

So, is this the sort of thing the Stack Exchange software can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some coding, it's probably possible. But it is antithetical to the purpose of Stack Exchange.

It is meant to be a public resource - that's why everything is posted under that [cc-wiki license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/). The objective is to serve the internet community as a whole, which is why [private versions of Stack Exchange have been discontinued](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions) and why people are allowed not only to view things anonymously, but also post their own questions or answers. To quote the [About Page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about), which gives some insight as to why it is easy to get information without commitment:

> Stack Overflow is as frictionless and painless to use as we could make it. We believe finding the right answer to your programming questions should be as easy as falling into the pit of success … and maybe even a little fun along the way.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I thought I would ask just to be safe. I like the idea of using Stack Exchange for this instead of trying to write it myself. Oh well, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Foxeris: you can try your luck with one of [these SE clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/146482)