# How much to set up a website like this?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an internal stack exchange for proprietary questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions)

I am a dedicated user of Stack Overflow, and now my team seems also interested in getting a similar website setup internally.

I am just wondering where I could find details about this, and terms and conditions also, as I am not that sort of business person to consider them always.