# Using Stack Overflow as a service

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Creating an internal stack exchange for proprietary questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions)
>   [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

I am wondering whether it is possible to use Stack Overflow as a service Q&A engine on our own web site? I know there are [OSQA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSQA) and other engine clones that we can install on our site, but this will not bring a community into it.

What we need is to have some sort of integration API, like other [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) do:

- An ability to set up design
  template with different heading,
  logos, backlinks, etc.
- Ability to
  pre-set tags in the URL, when the user
  clicks on a link to a specific forum on
  our web site.
- Ability to send
  e-mail notification when a new post
  with a specific tag appears on
  Stack Overflow (or any other API to
  trigger notification).

I’m sure development and software business web sites will be glad to pay for such service and advertising is also satisfactorily.

Any thoughts about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an internal stack exchange for proprietary questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions), [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Overflow Enterprise is available](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use, but it is really meant for larger organizations only. The only way to leverage the engine behind SO on  a public site is is via [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/) and their API.

Comment: They only have ability to filter posts by tags and to read them via RSS, so at least it covers third item in my request list. But what about posting questions with pre-set tags?