# Can Stack Exchange be used as a QA for a personal website?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an internal Stack Exchange for proprietary questions? [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55240/creating-an-internal-stack-exchange-for-proprietary-questions)

Is there a way to use the Stack Exchange engine as a forum for a personal website?

Like, virtually to have a separate database and the authenticated users of the website would be able to ask and answer questions.

Comment: I should point out that the accepted answer to the duplicate I suggested is _technically_ wrong. There is a private version of SE, but it's only offered to massive organizations. Like, Microsoft-sized. So, unless your personal website is Google, the answer is no. (If it _is_ Google, hi Larry's sockpuppet or Sergey's sockpuppet!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stack Overflow Enterprise is available](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise) for internal use, but it is really meant for larger organizations only.

For personal *public* sites, [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the Stack Exchange Network staging zone, has a [FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and it touches upon this:

> **Can I use Stack Exchange to support my product?**
>
> Stack Exchange does not offer a private label service for owning a Q&A site. You are free to create an expert Q&A site in your area of expertise. There is a lot of visibility and credibility to becoming a central figure in an expert community, but Stack Exchange is a product for the Internet community at large, not for corporations or individuals.

Regarding your specific question: it depends. Is your personal website dedicated to a topic that isn't already encompassed by a StackExchange site and would benefit from a Q&A site dedicated to the topic? If so, feel free to propose a site by clicking on the appropriate category on the left site of [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and then 'Propose a new [category] site' near the bottom.

The users of your site would have to register their own StackExchange accounts, however.

Answer (score 0):

**Stack Overflow is not a forum.**

And no, you can't.

You can propose a new site on [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: A new site created through area51 would not be a "personal site"

Comment: @JuanManuel: sure it isn't. I never said it