# Can you host the stackexchange software yourself to create a site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, hosting

I was wondering if I could create my own site using the software behind stackexchange and link back or retain some stackexchange branding so people know what the site is using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack Exchange for in-house use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/stack-exchange-for-in-house-use), but note the deprecation of the accepted answer, the true answer is [pop's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15753/stack-exchange-for-in-house-use/66698#66698) refering to [this blog entry about SE-2.0](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/). In short, you can no longer buy the engine but have to propose the site on http://area51.stackexchange.com and let the community decide whether it deserves your support

Comment: @Tobias Actually I thought SE 1.0 was still available for intranets.

Comment: @radp: interesting! can you find any post indicating that? to me the blog post suggested SE-1.0 will disappear with the exception of the last remaining public SE-1.0 sites that are also intended to turn SE-2.0

Comment: @Tobias http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69362/are-there-going-to-be-public-details-about-the-enterprise-version-of-se/69436#69436

Comment: @balpha♦: thanks, didn't notice that. So this question is a dupe of that, no?

Answer (score 10):

You can't buy the code anymore. But there are some [clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) that are open source. Or you can write your own.

Comment: Question2Answer [link]http://www.question2answer.org/[/link] looks like a stackoverflow clone